# SOQL Query for Left Join for custom objects

Tags: salesforce, soql, salesforce-lightning

I have a requirement to fetching data from Sales force. I need to get the data from two custom objects. I
have written query in sql can anyone help me to convert it into SOQL

```
SELECT ID, Name, Crop_Year__c, Targeted_Enrollment_Segments__c, Description__c, Start_Date__c, 
End_Date__c from Enrollment_Program__c EP
Left Join Account_Enrollment__c AE on EP.Crop_Year__c = AE.Crop_Year__c and EP.ID = 
AE.Enrollment_Program__c
where AE.Account__c = 'xyz'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know, Salesforce SOQL doesn't have explicit JOIN clauses. It does that for you implicitly based on related object fields. That means you'll have to query `Account_Enrollment__c` and traverse the fields to get the related `Enrollment_Program__c` Lookup relationship.

Another problem is Salesforce only performs joins based on primary and foreign keys, so the `EP.Crop_Year__c = AE.Crop_Year__c` in your query won't work.

So, with that said, you can try this:

```
SELECT Enrollment_Program__c, Enrollment_Program__e.Name,
 Enrollment_Program__r.Crop_Year__c, Enrollment_Program__r.Targeted_Enrollment_Segments__c,
 Enrollment_Program__r.Description__c, Enrollment_Program__r.Start_Date__c,
 Enrollment_Program__r.End_Date__c 
FROM Account_Entrollment_Program__c WHERE Account__c = 'zyz'
```

If you know beforehand what the `Crop_Year__c` value is, you can just add this to your query:

```
AND Crop_Year__c=:year AND Enrollment_Program__c.Crop_Year__c=:year
```

Some details on the queries:
The `__r` suffix is how you get the lookup object addressed in the query. If you are interested only in the id, you can use `__c`.
The `:year` is how you pass the parameter `year` to the query. If you want to append it as text you can just use `... Crop_Year='+ year + '`.